# Sometimes the dock and top bar do not appear on elementary Loki. What to do?

Tags: release-loki, boot, desktop

Sometimes the dock and top bar do not appear. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I usually just Ctrl+Alt+F2 login to command line and reboot. It then goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem intermittently, but it was due to a different bug and this fix solved it for me:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Intel Graphics card that's a known bug and it should be solved by now. Try updating your system (open AppCentre, go to Updates and press Update All).

Answer (score 0):

Still happening randomly at boot.

A solution faster than rebooting is to switch to another console and restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a logitech wireless mouse or keyboard?

If so, Try unplugging the receiver and see if the wingpanel comes back