# Pantheon doesn't load

Tags: wingpanel, plank, pantheon

Well my problem is that, lately it happens a lot.  When i turn on, nothing appears(wingpanel,dock) but only my wallpaper.  It's tiring to restart all the time the pc, and sometimes it doesn't even load on second or even third restart.
I tried once to re install pantheon via terminal (alt f2) but still happens
Any solutions?

Comment: İ have same problem. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please, add a bit more data. eOS Loki or Freya, your hardware, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377

This is the workaround: Significant lag loading panel and dock after login (Loki)

mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled

Comment: Newer issue: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/143

Answer (score 0):

This should help fix the issue without having to do a full reboot.

- switch to a console.

Ctrl + Alt + F2

- enter the following command.

  sudo service lightdm restart

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/11185/9042